# create script or alias which presents a command that the user can edit or execute by pressing enter

Tags: bash, git-bash

I want to create a bash script say `create_commit.sh` which will "present" command like `git commit -m 'edit this message'` at the command prompt. User can then edit the commit message and press enter to execute the command. How can I achieve this in bash?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick & dirty git-bash function template -

```
gitcom () {   # function to prompt for a commit message if not given
  if (( $# ))    # if there are args, assumes message typed on CLI
  then  msg="$*" # compose into one string 
  else echo "Please add a commit message in this format: 

         <branch_name_which_is_also_jira_id> rest of commit message 

        - use CTRL_D to end." > $(tty)
  msg="$(cat)"   # cat let's user type as many lines as they want
  fi
  git commit -m "$msg"  # uses msg from command line or prompt above
}
```

Use:

```
gitcom this is my unquoted commit message that is too short


gitcom "
  this is my message with info about what was changed and the jira ticket,
  done in one string over multiple lines, all passed as one argument.
"

gitcom # this is me letting the function prompt me for a message
Please add a commit message in this format: 

   <branch_name_which_is_also_jira_id> rest of commit message 

- use CTRL_D to end.

Here I'm typing stuff in over as many lines as I like, 
without CLI parsing. 

I can include blank lines, "quotes" of several 'types', and even some
funky <> $(...) metacharacters, because the cli isn't parsing this.

<CDTL_D>
```

We could also add some code to confirm the format...

Comment: thanks for the answer.  our organization requires the commit message to be in a specific format `git commit <branch_name_which_is_also_jira_id> rest of commit message` . So, I want to present a ready-made commit message to the user that meets the org requirement and also allow them to customize it if required.

Comment: Set the example in the prompt, which can be as many lines as you like.

Comment: @LincolnD have you looked into the `prepare-commit-msg` hook? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks It might help you more than what you're currently trying do to.

Comment: this is what I am doing right now

Comment: this is what I am doing right now `alias commit='git commit -m "\"commit on $(date +%Y%m%d) \""'`  . then type `commit` on the gitbash prompt and press `Ctrl + Alt + e`   Or `Esc` and `Ctrl + e`